# Prove that $\mathbb P(X=Y)=0$

Tags: probability, independence

> Prove that $\mathbb P(X=Y)=0$ if we know that $X,Y$ are independent random variables and for every $a$ we have $\mathbb P(X=a)=0$.

I did this task but I think that my proof is too easy and I afraid that it isn't correct answer:
$$\mathbb P(X=Y)=\sum_{a\in \mathbb R} \mathbb P(X=a \cap Y=a)=\sum_{a\in \mathbb R} \mathbb P(X=a)\cdot\mathbb P(Y=a)=\sum_{a\in \mathbb R} 0\cdot \mathbb P(Y=a)=0$$

Can anyone check it?

Comment: The first identity is incorrect because probability measures only have countable additivity.

Comment: In fact, since$$f(y):=E(I_{\{0\}}(X-y))=P(X=y)=0,\quad\forall y\in\mathbb R$$the independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies that$$P(X=Y\mid Y)=E(I_{\{0\}}(X-Y)\mid Y)=f(Y)=0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few more details on another answer (Fubini's Theorem not used):
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf P}(X=Y)
&=& 
\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\bf P}(X=Y|Y=y)dF_Y(y)\qquad \text{(by Law of Total Probability)}\\
&=&
\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\bf P}(X=y|Y=y)dF_Y(y)\qquad \text{(because of conditioning on }Y\text{)}\\
&=&
\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\bf P}(X=y)dF_Y(y)\qquad \text{(because of independence of } X,Y \text{)}\\
&=&
\int_{\mathbb{R}}0 dF_Y(y)\qquad \text{(because of assumption on } X\text{)}\\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

Your argument doesn't work because you are using 'uncountable additivity'.

$P(X=Y)=\int P(X=a) dF_Y(a)=\int 0dF_Y(a)=0$. The first equality is a consequence of Fubini's Theorem.